# Javascript adding Timezone in my current script

Tags: javascript, timezone

i have this code on my script to show ticking clock

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showTime() {
        var date = new Date(),
            time = new Date(Date.UTC(
                date.getFullYear(),
                date.getMonth(),
                date.getDate(),
                date.getHours(),
                date.getMinutes(),
                date.getSeconds()
            ));

        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time.toLocaleTimeString();
    }

    setInterval(showTime, 1000);

</script>
```

Anyone know how to change the timezone to a specific timezone like "Asia/Jakarta"
Thanks before!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for info : [list of TZ (Time Zone)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

you can change `undefined` to `'en-US'` => get a country-specific presentation
(`en-US` is AM/PM, `fr-FR` -> 24h format, `undefined` -> local browser format)

see also : [Javascript HTML Multiple Timezone Clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60759088/javascript-html-multiple-timezone-clock/60760569#60760569)

```js
const
  timeLocal   = document.querySelector('#time-Local span')
, timeLA      = document.querySelector('#time-US-LA span')
, timeJakarta = document.querySelector('#time-Jakarta span')
;

let currentDate = new Date();

timeLocal.textContent   = currentDate.toLocaleTimeString()
timeLA.textContent      = currentDate.toLocaleTimeString(undefined, {timeZone:'America/Los_Angeles'} )
timeJakarta.textContent = currentDate.toLocaleTimeString(undefined, {timeZone:'Asia/Jakarta'} )
```

```css
p      { width: 16em; }
p span { float: right;}
```

```html
<p id="time-Local"> local time: <span></span> </p>
<p id="time-US-LA"> Los_Angeles time: <span></span> </p>
<p id="time-Jakarta"> Jakarta time: <span></span> </p>
```

Comment: Thanks sir, finally i found the simple way!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this.
usaTime = date.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});

Comment: what part should i change?

Comment: instead of  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time.toLocaleTimeString();

                                                                                                                                    
  use below::
                                                                                                            
asiaTime = date.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Jakarta"});
 document.getElementById('asiaTime').innerHTML = asiaTime.toLocaleTimeString();

Comment: Thanks Naidu!, I appreciate your answer!

Comment: correction, you should use en-IN for india timings if you are looking for.